# .htaccess trouble with double variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

iam working on the htaccess of my website.

I've got this piece of .htacess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9]+).html$ index.php?lang=$2&seo=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z0-9]+).html$ index?seo=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What iam looking with this .htaccess is this: `http://mywebsite.com/en/test-page.html` insted of `http://mywebsite.com/index.php?lang=en&seo=test-page` taking on count "en" as "lang" and "test-page" as "seo".

The problem is that this throws me a 404 error.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this i think problem is for `index?seo` that must be `index.php?seo` and skip flag that if you put it `S=1` when pattern match skip one  RewriteRule after it

```
 RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9]+).html$ index.php?lang=$1&seo=$2 [S=1,QSA,L]

 RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z0-9]+).html$ index.php?seo=$1 [QSA,L]
```

if you want pass query too use this

```
 RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9]+).html(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&seo=$2$3 [S=1,QSA,L]

 RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z0-9]+).html(.*)$ index.php?seo=$1$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slashes from your regex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?lang=$1&seo=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?seo=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also, keep in mind that `RewriteCond` applies to only one `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Tried but no luck with this one.

Comment: @JoseCardama Hm, try redirecting to the url to see what you get: `[R,QSA,L]`

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9]+)\.html$ pages/anime.php?lang=$1&seo=$2 [R,QSA,L] that sends me to the index page, same as before.

Comment: @JoseCardama I think it might have something to do with the `RewriteBase`. Could you give me the exact url you go to and the exact one you get redirected to?

Comment: http://mywebsite.com/en/test-page.html redirects to http://mywebsite.com/index.php

Comment: well it seems I fixed it like this: RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?lang=$1&seo=$2 [NC,L]